# spring boot java scheduler should be executed only once for three dyno's per day

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, concurrency

i have spring boot and java application. at particular time of the day it should execute a method. so in the production server  we have kept 4 dyno's and because of 4 dyno's it is executing 4 times per day. so i have used cache and getting the date . based on the date i try to execute the method only once .still it is executing 4 times.

```
  @Scheduled(zone = "${scheduler.zone}", cron = "${scheduler.cron.job}")
  public  void processScheduled() {

   
    synchronized(this) {
      LocalDate localDate = redisTemplate.getValue("DATE");
      if (localDate == null || LocalDate.now().isAfter(localDate)) {
        log.info("Entered process in SchedulerConfig");
        redisTemplate.putValue("DATE", LocalDate.now());
        schedulerService.processScheduled();
      }
    }
  }
```

the above code is written in a config java class.

1. the schedulerService.processScheduled(); should be triggered only once a day irrespective of no of the dyno's.
   can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using Heroku Dynos, so there are 4 separate instances of your app running in production. Since there are 4 separate instances, your use of `synchronized` will be of little use here. All 4 of your instances are getting invoked at the same time, so there is a chance that, all of them will get the value of `redisTemplate.getValue("DATE")` as not null. You need an atomic operation with an centralized entity. Redis does serve as an centralized entity, but `redisTemplate.getValue("DATE")` and then `redisTemplate.putValue("DATE", LocalDate.now())` is not an atomic operation. So it is very possible that 4 instances call `redisTemplate.getValue("DATE")` and get the real date. Since all 4 of them are not null, they will all update the value and then process your operation.

You should try using `redisTemplate.delete(key)`. It is an atomic operation which returns true if the key is deleted else returns false. So your code may look like this.

```
@Scheduled(zone = "${scheduler.zone}", cron = "${scheduler.cron.job}")
public  void processScheduled() {
  
      boolean isDeleted= redisTemplate.delete("DATE"); // only one will get true, other will get false.

      if (isDeleted) {
        log.info("Entered process in SchedulerConfig");
      
        schedulerService.processScheduled();

        // sleep for some time and then update the date value
        redisTemplate.putValue("DATE", LocalDate.now());

      }
    
  }
```

Or you can update the Date value after some time of the invocation with @Scheduled

```
@Scheduled(zone = "${scheduler.zone}", cron = "${scheduler.flag.update.job}")
public  void updateDateFlag() {
    redisTemplate.putValue("DATE", LocalDate.now());
}
```

Comment: this is working fine when requests comes at same time. some times dyno's come with a gap of seconds , that time it is executing scheduler second time.

Comment: Yes, I also noticed that, redistemplate.putValue inside if is the culprit. You need to populate the date flag after the invocation time span. You can use another @Scheduled or sleep for some time before setting the date value.